# Navigation stack parameters tuning to pass through a narrow space

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've already applied nav stack to my own robot(it's not omni, but diff)
and now I'm tuning parameters.

I'd like to make the robot to pass through a narrow space
which consits of a wall and obstacle.
However, when it comes close to the space, it stucks.

Concretely speaking, when it comes close to the narrow space,
it does the followings.

**(1) goes closer to the wall or obstacle in a very low velocity(I think it's strange behavior).

(2) goes back or rotate a little.

(3) continues (1) and (2) permanently without recovery behaviors(Local minimum ??).**

Actually, when I put a obstacle very close(about 20cm) to the robot,
it behaves in the manner.

I'd like to know ...
**(1)What parameters are important to avoid above problems ?**
(footprint, inflation_radiusm pass_distance_bias, goal_distance_bias, occdist_scale?)
**(2)If it's not the parameters' problem, could you tell me how to solve it ?**

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52549/navigation-stack-parameters-tuning-to-pass-through-a-narrow-space/) by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 721 on 2013-01-16

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I had the same problem. Finally I solved it by reducing the inflation radius in the local map, and setting the inflation radius of the global map a little higher than the radius of the robot.

Playing with this two parameters I realized that the robot wont never travel through a zone that contains an inflated obstacle of the local costmap. If you set this value high, the robot wont pass through a narrow space. The obstacles on the global costmap allows to control the distance between the trayectory and the obstacles, so that will prevent the collision.

Hope it helps you ;)

---

Originally posted by [g.aterido](https://answers.ros.org/users/2783/g.aterido/) with karma: 229 on 2013-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damjan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2702/damjan/) on 2013-01-17**:
Same thing worked for me on a Pioneer 3-DX robot. Reducing the inflation radius in the local map had by far the biggest effect on the robot's ability to pass through narrow spaces.

**Comment by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on 2013-01-29**:
Thank you for your answers ! I reduced inflation radius from 0.5 to 0.3 and adjusted footprint very tightly, then the robot could pass through narrow space.